# How to provide props to custom route in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-admin

I'm using reac-admin, and want that after edit to redirect the user to custom route.

```
  <Edit {...props}>
        <TabbedForm redirect={redirect(`/XXX/${props.id}/YYY`)}  >

       {/* fileds */}

        </TabbedForm >
  </Edit>
```

in the custom routes I have this route:

```
    <Route exact path="/XXX/:id/YYY" render={(props) => <MyRoute {...props} />} />
```

My problem is how to pass props like in show?

why when redirect to show :  `redirect="show"`, the props which are passed are different than when redirect to a custom route?

There are missed props which I need them like the id.

What sholud I do to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You have two ways to do that:

### First option

```
<Route exact path="/XXX/:id/YYY" render={() => <MyRoute />} />
```

And inside MyRoute:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

const MyRoute = () => {
    let { id } = useParams();
    // ...
}
```

### Second option

```
<Route exact path="/XXX/:id/YYY" render={(props) => <MyRoute id={props.match.params.id} />} />
```